# What advantages does the Brenizer method have over Photoshop blur?

Tags: photoshop, technique, depth-of-field, wide-angle, brenizer-method

I have seen a lot of posts lately about the [Brenizer method](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8508/what-is-bokeh-panorama-also-called-the-brenizer-method).  It looks smashing, but at the same time, I am fairly certain I could recreate the look using blurred layers in Photoshop.  Apart from having a high-resolution picture using Brenizer's technique, are there other advantages I'm missing from just taking one wide-angle shot and manipulating it in PS to mimic the look?

Comment: Related: [Real-time vs post-production blurs — what's the difference?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23523/real-time-vs-post-production-blurs-whats-the-difference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most techniques that are 'properly' accomplished in-camera, but can also be approximated in software, are generally better in-camera. No software filter can replicate the quality of bokeh afforded by a good-quality lens (although Photoshop's Lens Blur filter does a decent job).

Having said that, the Brenizer method *is* relatively time consuming, both in the field and in the computer, and requires a fast lens, so whether or not you do it 'properly' or with straightforward blurring really depends on what you're doing with it. If you're just taking a family portrait shot, you may as well 'cheat'. If you're taking a shot for your portfolio or for a professional wedding shoot, it's worth going the whole hog.

Comment: They are comparing one post processing technique to another, neither option is in camera.

Comment: The shallow depth of field and multiple exposures are in-camera, the shots are then just stitched together in post processing.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall, this is pretty much what I was thinking in terms of why I'd ever use the Brenzier method.  So I'm not missing anything really other than 'photo-geek drooling-grade bokeh' and a larger final image, correct?

Comment: Well, that's subjective. The only way to be sure yourself is to try both methods and see if you care much about the difference.